# Java To iOS client streams reading junk characters

Tags: java, ios, sockets, encoding, stream

I'm working on an iOS app that talks to a Java client using NSStreams and sockets.

They're talking to each other fine, but on the iOS side, I'm frequently logging out some strange characters coming through at the end of the received string. The Java client on the other hand seems to read everything the iOS app send it exactly as expected.

The patterns of junk characters are between 5 and about 30 characters long and their pattens look fairly similar. They invariably include lots of upside down question marks.

I've included my code. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or how to eliminate these unwanted characters?

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
    switch (streamEvent) {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {

            uint8_t buffer[100];
            [(NSInputStream *)theStream  read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
            NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:100 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            if (s.length>1) {
                CLS_LOG(@"Read: %@",s);
                [self handleRecievedMessage:s];
            }
```

and on the Java server

```
    DataOutputStream out;
    out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    byte[] msg = messageToSend.getBytes();
    out.write(msg);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rmaddy was right about the problem being how much I'm reading from the stream. Here's the code I'm using now, which no longer reads any junk characters.

```
- (void)readFromStream{
int BUFFER_LEN = 512;

uint8_t *buffer;
NSUInteger length;
BOOL freeBuffer = NO;
// The stream has data. Try to get its internal buffer instead of creating one
if(![inputStream getBuffer:&buffer length:&length]) {
    // The stream couldn't provide its internal buffer. We have to make one ourselves
    buffer = malloc(BUFFER_LEN * sizeof(uint8_t));
    freeBuffer = YES;
    NSInteger result = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:BUFFER_LEN];
    length = result;
}

if (buffer != NULL) {
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if (s.length>1) {
        CLS_LOG(@"Read: %@",s);
        [self handleRecievedMessage:s];
    }
}

// length bytes of data in buffer
if(freeBuffer) free(buffer);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should properly deal with how many characters you actually read from the stream. Try this in place of the two lines you have:

```
NSInteger len = [(NSInputStream *)theStream  read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Cheers for your answer. You correctly identified the problem. I've posted the full code I'm using as the answer.